# I am not able to execute this function. The code doesn't have errors in itself but execution fails. I want to know what the error is?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, nft

This is the function in which I am trying to create an instance of another contract.

```
function createAuction(uint256 _bidIncrement, uint256 _timeInDays) public {
        uint256 currentBlock = block.number;
        Auction newAuction = new Auction(
            owner,
            currentBlock,
            currentBlock + endBlock(_timeInDays),
            _bidIncrement
        );
        auctions.push(address(newAuction));
    }
```

And [this](https://github.com/vromahya/auction/blob/main/auction.sol) is the contract that I want to create an instance of.

What is the error in the following code?
Here is what remixIDE shows

```
> transact to demoMar.createAuction pending ... 
transact to demoMar.createAuction errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: can you post the script you're using to call the function....I think that's the issue (you're trying to send value apparently)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `Auction` contract require statements

```
constructor(
    address payable _auctioneer,
    uint256 _startBlock,
    uint256 _endBlock,
    uint256 _bidIncrement
) {
    require(_startBlock >= _endBlock);
    require(_startBlock < block.number);
    auctioneer = _auctioneer;
    startBlock = _startBlock;
    endBlock = _endBlock;
    bidIncrement = _bidIncrement;
    auctionState = auc_State.running;
}
```

In the call `_startBlock = block.number`, so the condition here `require(_startBlock < block.number)` is false so it will revert.

Probably the conditions should be reversed.

```
require(_startBlock <= _endBlock);
require(_startBlock > block.number);
```